# What does this mean?

Tags: android, callback

> By the same token, a service that attempts to support multiple callback clients may find itself starved for CPU resources, even if all the clients are relatively well behaved. Whereas addTextChangedListener supports the subscription of multiple clients, many of the callbacks in the Android library support only one. With these callbacks (setOn KeyListener, for instance), setting a new client for a particular callback on a particular object replaces any previous client.The previously registered client will no longer receive any callback notifications. In fact, it won’t even be notified that it is no longer the client. The newly registered client will, thenceforward, receive all notifications.

I am learning Android programming from a book and it introduced the concept of adding listeners.
I know what listeners are and what they do from my little Java experience.

However, I do not understand what is stated in the above paragraph.
**Please eluidate**

Comment: they(authors) trying to explain what is the differences between `add` and `set` ...

Comment: @Selvin Can you please elaborate ? :-) AFAIK, plain-old-Java has only `addXXXListener` and not `set` so I am kinda confused here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a callback listener on an event, there are generally two ways of doing so:

```
private MyEventListener listener;

...

public void setEventListener(MyEventListener listener){
     this.listener = listener;
}

...

// some event later on
this.listener.callback(interestingData);
```

Here, every time you set the listener from a client class, you replace the existing listener.  Only the client which last set the listener will receive a call back.

The other way is like this:

```
private ArrayList<MyEventListener> listeners;

...

public void setEventListener(MyEventListener listener){

     if (listeners == null){
        listeners = new ArrayList<MyEventListener>();
     }

     if(!listeners.contains(listener){
        listeners.add(listener);
     }

}

...

// some event later on
for(MyEventListener listener:listeners){
    listener.callback(interestingData);
}
```

The problem with the second approach is that you cannot control how many clients receive callbacks and with a lot of clients registered, they might consume a lot of CPU handling the callbacks.

You could artificially limit the number of listeners (`if(listeners.count() < 5)`) but that doesn't make sense from an OOP perspective.

Which one is right depends on your design.  I usually use the latter pattern since I know how many clients there will be and the number is small (usually less than 5).

Comment: So this is substantially different from the usual Java event handling, right ? Java only allows one listener per GUI component.

Comment: Yes, substantially different.  In fact, the method would be better named `addEventListener` since `set` implies only one.

Answer (score 1):

My attempt to paraphrase:

Allowing the setting of multiple listeners can be a resource hog as you have to notify all the clients.

Some Android listeners (like addTextChangeListener) support being set for multiple clients.

However, most don't and the last client you set is the one that will get the notifications.

Comment: I guess by client I mean "implementation of a listener" - `EditText.setOnKeyListener(listener1); EditText.setOnKeyListener(listener2);` `listener2` gets the notifications